# Scroll Images with Random Start Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following markup:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/525x160" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/525x170" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/525x180" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/525x190" />
</div>
```

with css:

```
.image {
    position:relative;
}
.image img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

I want to cycle through the images. This works fine if I start at image 0:

```
$('.image img:gt(0)').hide(); // to hide all but the first image when page loads

setInterval(function () {
    $('.image :first-child').fadeOut(1000)
        .next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('.image');
}, 5000);
```

, but when I pick a random start image it starts with this image visible, but then fades in image 2 when it should fade in [random image number]+1

```
var imgNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
$('.image img:gt(' + imgNum + ')').hide(); //hide all images except the randomly picked one

setInterval(function () {
    $('.image :first-child').fadeOut(1000)
        .next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('.image');
}, 5000);
```

[Original Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DS3qq/)

[Random number Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattwilkinson/SpLpA/39/)

Comment: both giving same output

Comment: @user2648239 - apologies: fiddle links were broken. Should now be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the **[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DS3qq/11/)**

JS Code

```
var maxImg = $('.image img').length,
    startImg = Math.floor((Math.random()*maxImg)+1);
$('.image img').hide();
$('.image img:nth-child('+startImg+')').show();
setInterval(function () {
    $('.image img:visible').fadeOut(1000);
    if(startImg+1 > maxImg) 
      startImg = 1;
    else 
      startImg++;
    console.log(startImg);
    $('.image img:nth-child('+startImg+')').fadeIn(1000);
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DS3qq/14/)

I've left the JS fairly long winded so you can follow:

```
var imgNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
var images=[];
var imgStart=null;
$.each($('.image img'), function(index, img){
    images.push(img);
    if(index!=imgNum){
        $(img).hide();
    }
})
var counter=imgNum;
var interval=setInterval(function () {  
    $(images[counter]).fadeOut(1000);
    counter++;
    counter>=images.length && (counter=0);
    $(images[counter]).fadeIn(1000);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This seems to be cycling 160,170,190,180,160... for some reason

Comment: Do you not want the images to cycle back to the start indefinitely?

Comment: I've updated so the images dont cycle back to the start if you dont want :)

Comment: No I want to cycle indefinitely but in sequence so if the third image is randomly picked on load it would be 3,1,2,3,4,... your example was giving 3,1,2,4,3, for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not hiding all the images except the random-indexed one, you are hiding only the images having index greater than the random-generated, with this code:

```
$('.image img:gt(' + imgNum + ')').hide();
```

You can use `:visible` selector, and change the above code with

```
$('.image img:gt(' + imgNum + '), .image img:lt(' + imgNum + ')').hide();
```

This way, you hide ALL the images except the one random-selected

**JS**

```
var imgNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
$('.image img:gt(' + imgNum + '), .image img:lt(' + imgNum + ')').hide();

setInterval(function () {
    $('.image img:visible').fadeOut(1000)
        .next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('.image');
}, 5000);
```

**fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/DS3qq/7/

---

**FIXED LOOP**

```
var imgNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
$('.image img:gt(' + imgNum + '), .image img:lt(' + imgNum + ')').hide();
var count = $('.image img').length;

setInterval(function () {
    $('.image img:eq('+ (imgNum++) +')').fadeOut(1000);
    if(imgNum >= count){
        imgNum = 0;
    } 
    $('.image img:eq('+ (imgNum) +')').fadeIn(1000)
}, 5000);
```

**UPDATED FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/DS3qq/15/

Comment: Thanks - this nearly works except that if an image other than 160 is picked as the start image, it doesn't cycle back to that image after 190

Comment: @MattWilko you are right, sorry. I've added the updated fiddle, I changed a little bit the code